# how to reduce PHP script's execution speed

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance, slowdown

I am running a big scheduling application which sometimes makes alot of loops and calculations and inserts tens of thousands of records in a mysql database.

The script runs for about 10-15 seconds. Problem is the script demands too much of the server's CPU and mysql power.

Anyway to slow down the scripts demand for power so as not to arouse the wrath of my shared server host? (assuming it's already optimized)

the big bottleneck is the thousands of mysql inserts and one mysql delete of thousands of records.

I thought of using sleep() between queries but was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: That's an... usual... request for once. I'd say if you are in danger of being terminated for doing what you need to do, use another host; likely non-shared.

Comment: I think this cannot be answered without **analyzing** the whole code. and who's gonna do that it is a big question !!

Comment: the big bottleneck is the thousands of mysql inserts and one mysql delete of thousands of records.

Comment: I am also doing some calculations how can I optimize them? I was thinking about writing an optimize function, but will it help? I hope that it is clear that neither my nor your 'pseudo question' can not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

As i think you do lot of things in nested loops, due to this the complexity of loops goes in multiple of (n) that why it take to much time in your script. Apart from this you should create the procedure for insertions to reduce the complexity of query.
actually you need to implement profilling to optimize your codes.

Comment: thanks but bottleneck is mostly from mysql inserts and those are optimized

Comment: you should use profiler to watch/reduce the time of your codes.